# Where is the mnemonic stored in Daedalus?

Tags: wallet, daedalus

I'd like to know where the mnemonic (if at all) is stored in the Daedalus directory. I am running on Ubuntu 20.04, and I'd like to extract the mnemonic from the filesystem. (Assuming I am not using a hardware wallet).

Answer (score 3):

Mnemonic is used to make it easier for us to create the root private key (for signing transactions). When you insert your mnemonic, behind the scene it's actually using the **BIP39** mechanism to create the **root private key**. And this private key is the one that is actually being stored, *not* the mnemonic seed phrase itself. If you'd like, you can 'walk back' the private key into a mnemonic seed phrase, but it's quite tasking.

I don't really know much about the Daedalus wallet, but with a light wallet (Like Eternl, Nami, Yoroi, etc), the private key is stored encrypted with your wallet password.

References on how **BIP39** and **Key Derivation works** in Cardano:

- https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/technical-concepts#mnemonic-seed-phrase-bip39
- https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/technical-concepts#key-derivation

In newer Daedalus, **there isn't any information regarding the location of the secret.key**, only in older Daedalus.

- https://iohk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/900000623463-Importing-wallets
- https://forum.cardano.org/t/where-are-the-public-and-private-keys-located-in-daedalus/6522